# codeigniter routing functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a small problem with routing.

My routes:

```
$route['category/(:any)/(:num)'] = "site/index/$2"; //not working
$route['category/(:any)'] = "site/index"; //not working
$route['category/(:any)/(:any)'] = "site/view/$2"; // working
$route['Search'] = "site/search"; // working
```

What I want: http://example.com/category/Home - call site/index function
http://example.com/category/Home/2 call site/index function with parameter $2 
I'm geting 404 erro at those 2 rules.

What I tried was to echo the parameter of category/(:any)/(:num) and it echoed it. This echo was inside the index function. The views adn models exists in the paths I declared. The index page itself wouldn't work without it. So I think the problem has to be in routing

The most interesting thing is that when I change the category/(:any) route to site/view it is working but when I set there site/index it is not working. Even if I set there only site .

Comment: remove your route and retry. It should automaticly route to the correct action. As explained [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html), default behaviour is `example.com/class/function/id/`.

Comment: I tried to remove the route and add it again but nothing happend. If the route is not there it call the site/view function

Comment: Ok... I see what's your problem

Comment: Well actually, all your routes are weired. ie : `$route['(:any)']` will point to site. That means, whatever you type, you go to `site`. This is massive duplicate content.

Comment: Yeah your routes are all kinds of messed up I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Yes I found out it now and I'm trying to add smoe more params to the urls. The idea of this was to call the site controller on example.com/Home which would output all the articles in home section

Comment: Fixed, I found an error in my controller. I was passing wrong uri segment to view db datas. Thanks for your patient guys and also for recomendations. Also I fixed the admin thing too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is to have your `site` class as "default controller". Just try this :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['(:any)'] = "site/view/$1";
$route['(:num)'] = "site/index/$1";
```

I don't really know what you are trying to do with your `site/view/$1` and `site/index/$1` it will work like this :

`example.com/someaction` will match `$route['(:any)']` and will call the `view` method of the `site` controller with `someaction` as a string parameter.

`example.com/2` will match `$route['(:num)']` and call the `index` action of the `site` controller with `2` as an integer parameter.

`example.com/admin` will call the `index` action of the `admin` controller

`example.com/admin/category` will call the `category` action of the `admin` controller

Comment: I'm routing it from begining. This wouldnt do it because the site/index/$1 is for pagination and every category has its own number of articles. Now what I have is the only rule `$route['category/(:any)'] = "site/index";` after going to example.com/category/Home I get 404. I'm confused..

Edit: If I set rule to "site/view" it pass me to view function but if I want index function it will not let me.

Comment: that's because you forgot the parameter : `$route['category/(:any)'] = "site/index/$1";`. Try reading a bit more the doc.

Comment: the index function does not need a parameter and I tried also this and it was not working either. Tried one more time just in case now and still not working

Comment: Again, read more the doc. If you want you can try explaining exactly what behaviour you are expecting in your question (which uri should point to which method, ...)